# Dimensions in package outline

Tags: datasheet, packages

I don't really know what is with those stacked dimensions 5.00/4.90/4.80
on the ADP1708 package drawing.

[image: dimensions for ADP1078]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4.90 nominal, 5.00 maximum, 4.80 minimum.

Some other dimensions are min/max and a few are just nominal, reference or 'basic' dimensions.

Comment: Thank you! For a moment I thought that every IC have its own dimensions ADP1706/5.00 ADP1707/4.90 ADP1708/4.80

Comment: Ah, I can see how you might guess that. One hint that isn't true is that the package reference is singular (or two names that point to the same package- SOIC_N_EP and RD-8-2) .There may well be chips covered on different datasheets which use that same package.